# Flickering UIView in simulator using Playground

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift-playground

I'm running Xcode 6.4, playing with playground, I write this super basilar code.

I would like to run the code in the simulator so I opened utility tab (alt-cmd-0)
and selected the checkbook " [v] Run in Full Simulator "

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let eenView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
eenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()

XCPShowView("View", eenView)
```

The simulator is showing, and also the view, but... it's Flickering!!

*(I ve tried a lot of stuff like reset all the simulators, creating new ones, nothing seems work, I'm wondering if I need to add something in my code)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

```
import UIKit

//setup

struct MainScene {
    let vc: UIViewController
    let nc: UINavigationController
    init(vc: UIViewController) {
        self.vc = vc
        self.nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    class func viewController(color: UIColor) -> UIViewController {
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        vc.view.backgroundColor = color
        return vc
    }
}

let vc = UIViewController.viewController(UIColor.lightGrayColor())
vc.title = "title"

////////Write your prototype code there

////////End of your prototype

let mainScene = MainScene(vc: vc)

//Run playground
let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
window.rootViewController = mainScene.nc
window.makeKeyAndVisible()
CFRunLoopRun()
```

this is the solution, if someone is interested...

I modified the code of ilyapuchka (He realized really good examples):

https://gist.github.com/ilyapuchka/1ae19259161a91f3a8a8